# plesk API returns You have entered incorrect username or password for creating subdomains

Tags: c#, subdomain, plesk, parallels

I'm trying to create a sub-domain using C# in Parallels Plesk Panel 11.
Which username and Password should i enter for the requests I'm sending?!
What ever username and password I enter I receive error:

> " You have entered incorrect username or password. "

Can I interact with the panel as a normal user? or do I need a special authority from the administrators?
My current access level to the panel is OWNER

**UPDATE:**
Maybe its necessary to mention that my website is in a shared hosting server and until now I tried to do this with my panel account and also FTP account...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For "Admin and "Customer" there is no need special permissions. "Customer" is always "Owner" of his subscriptions.

"Reseller" should be created by plan with special permission "Ability to use remote API"

"Auxiliary Users" has no access to API and get

```
<status>error</status>
<errcode>1006</errcode>
<errtext>Permission denied.</errtext>
```

If you get

```
<status>error</status>
<errcode>1001</errcode>
<errtext>You have entered incorrect username or password.</errtext>
```

it may be password/username is wrong or it MAY be a bug if some special char in password/username.